# Refreshing Listview after Append or HTML

Tags: javascript, listview, cordova, dynamic, refresh

I've been searching for this problem but no one works for me.

I have this HTML

```
<div id="divHistorialListView">
     <ul data-role="listview" id="listHistorial">
     </ul>
</div>
```

and this in a Javascript function

```
$("#listHistorial").append("<li><a href='jjj'>hola!</a></li>");
$("#listHistorial").listview();
```

and I run the functions many times. The first run it format the listview perfect. The second one (and all after the second!) formats wrong! (like a normal ul or worst)

I tried also:

```
$("#listHistorial").listview("refresh");
```

and

```
$("#listHistorial").refresh();
```

but when I try these, some code in javascript don't run (as if were an error and the function be ignored completely)

I also searched the JQuery Mobile site and there it says to use those... but no resutls!

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#listHistorial").listview().listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I think the thing is to understand what the methods do... in everypost I read it says "try this" or "try that" but don't explain and we end copypasting like crazy.

I'm gonna explain what I understood of this:

.listview() // CREATES A LISTVIEW FROM SCRATCH and DON'T WORK WITH APPEND. If the list ALREADY EXISTS DON'T WORK EITHER because it's already created.

.listview("refresh") // REFRESH AN EXISTING LISTVIEW (IF NOT EXISTS, DON'T REFRESH ;D)

so I end up doing this:

HTML (pre create the EMPTY ListView)

```
<ul id="myListview" data-role="listview">
</ul>
```

Javascript (populate the ListView)

```
$("#mylistview").empty(); 
for (bla bla bla)
{
    $("#mylistview").append("<li><a href="">blablalba</a><li>");
}
$("#mylistview").listview("refresh");
```

This worked for me!

Comment: .listview() is used to initialize the list before adding stuff in it.

Comment: yes! but i've found that only works when the list wasn't created... if it's created isn't necessary. For example, when in html code you didn't define the <ul>, and you do it by $("#div").html(), then you need to initialize it (to inform jqm that it's a listview and then format it)